# Java Graph library for Network visualization by Graph

Tags: java, networking, data-visualization, graphs

I want to Implement a visualization interface for visualizing `nodes` and `edges` as graph and some objects like nodes moving between the nodes as **Data packets** Like the image below:

[image]

I have tried using the **Jung** library but it lacks any kind of feature for moving objects between the nodes using the edges as the *path* for the moving object.
I have seen the demo of Graph Stream Library that shows some objects moving between nodes but when I looked at the library documentation I didn't find any feature for moving things in the graph, Is this library capable of my need?

If not can anybody suggest a library that can provide me such functionality.
Any suggestions would be appreciated.

**EDIT :   Further efforts in implementation**

I am already implementing such functionality in **JUNG** and for straight edges it works fine, I am using the `IterativeProcess` class and moving the nodes by `setLocation` function.

But I was wondering is there really a better way of doing this by some other library that has some internal defined functionality for doing such thing?